# Pulling the Next Value Under the Same Column Header

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, csv

I am using Python's `csv` module to read ".csv" files and parse them out to MySQL insert statements. In order to maintain syntax for the statements I need to determine the type of the values listed under each column header. However, I have run into a problem as some of the rows start with a `null` value.

How can I use the `csv` module to return the next value under the same column until the value returned is **not** `null`? This does not have to be accomplished with the `csv` module; I am open to all solutions. After looking through the documentation I am not sure that the `csv` module is capable of doing what I need. I was thinking something along these lines:

```
if rowValue == '':
    rowValue = nextRowValue(row)
```

Obviously the `next()` method simply returns the next value in the csv "list" rather than returning the next value under the same column like I want, and the `nextRowValue()` object does not exist. I am just demonstrating the idea.

*Edit:* Just to add some context, here is an example of what I am doing and the problems I am running into.

If the table is as follows:

```
ID Date Time  Voltage Current Watts
0  7/2  11:15         0       0
0  7/2  11:15         0       0
0  7/2  11:15  380    1       380
```

And here is a very slimmed down version of the code that I am using to read the table, get the column headers and determine the type of the values from the first row. Then put them into separate lists and then use `deque` to add them to insert statements in a separate function. Not all of the code is featured and I might have left some crucial parts out, but here is an example:

```
import csv, os
from collections import deque

def findType(rowValue):
    if rowValue == '':
        rowValue = 
    if '.' in rowValue:
        try:
            rowValue = type(float(rowValue))
        except ValueError:
            pass
    else:
        try:
            rowValue = type(int(rowValue))
        except:
            rowValue = type(str(rowValue))
    return rowValue

def createTable():
    inputPath = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/test_input/'
    outputPath = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/test_output/'
    for file in os.listdir(inputPath):
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            with open(inputPath + file) as inFile:
                with open(outputPath + file[:-4] + '.sql', 'w') as outFile:
                    csvFile = csv.reader(inFile)
                    columnHeader = next(csvFile)
                    firstRow = next(csvFile)
                    cList = deque(columnHeader)
                    rList = deque(firstRow)
                    hList = []
                    for value in firstRow:
                        valueType = findType(firstRow)
                        if valueType == str:
                            try:
                                val = '`' + cList.popleft() + 'varchar(255)'
                                hList.append(val)
                            except IndexError:
                                pass
                        etc.
```

And so forth for the rest of the value types returned from the findType function. The problem is that when adding the values to rList using `deque` it skips over `null` values so that the number of items in the list for column headers would be 6, for example, and the number of items in the list for rows would be 5 so they would not line up.

A somewhat drawn out solution would be to scan each row for `null` values until one was found using something like this:

```
for value in firstRow:
     if value == '':
         firstRow = next(csvFile)
```

And continuing this loop until a row was found with no `null` values. However this seems like a somewhat drawn out solution that would slow down the program, hence why I am looking for a different solution.

Comment: show a few lines of your input file, and identify which lines cause problems

Comment: @joelgoldstick Edited.

Comment: When you read a line with csv.reader you should get a list.  Check the length of the list.  If it doesn't contain enough fields, go to the next line without processing that line

Comment: Very similar to the solution I posted in the edit except it skips the need to read through each row. The only problem would be if the reader counted `null` values as a part of the list since they are put into the list as `''`. This would be much better as it wouldn't slow down the program so I'll mess around with it and see how it goes.

Comment: Looks like the problem is that null values are still added to the list as `''` and therefore are counted towards the total number of items in the list. So even though the row list contains a null value it would still return the same number of values as the column list, therefore your solution would not work. See below for how I went about solving it.

Comment: in python-speak, they are empty strings.  There is something called None, but nothing called null.  But you can still test for if "" in your_csv_list.  That might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than pull the next value from the column as the title suggests, I found it easier to just skip rows that contained any `null` values. There are two different ways to do this:

Use a loop to scan each row and see if it contains a `null` value, and jump to the next row until one is found that contains no `null` values. For example:

```
tempRow = next(csvFile)
for value in tempRow:
    if value == '':
       tempRow = next(csvFile)
    else:
       row = tempRow
```